# How do I get Liberator Exception Info?

Tags: debugging, clojure, middleware, liberator

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get Exception debug information out of liberator. I make a request via clj-http and get:

```
17-05-08 15:26:09 x201 DEBUG [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection:128] - 
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
{:status 500, :headers {"Server" "nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)", "Date" "Mon, 08 May 2017 15:26:09 GMT", "Content-Length" "0", "Connection" "close"}, 
 :body "", :request-time 45, 
 :trace-redirects ["http://api.mysite.dev/0/projects/Food-Blog/data/Ar6D3PjBZv"], :orig-content-encoding nil}
```

I have liberator `wrap-trace` in my middleware list and it doesn't seem to give me the actual Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `handle-exception` handler which will render the response if an exception is thrown.